# printk inside an interrupt handler , is it really that bad?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, interrupt-handling, printk

everybody knows that interrupt handler should be short as possible. and adding functions like `printk` for debugging inside an interrupt handler is something that shouldn't be done.
Actually, I tried it before when I was debugging the linux kernel for an interrupt driven char device I written, and it wrecked the timing of the driver.

The question I have, is why this is happening ?
`printk` function is buffered ! it means, as far as I understand that the data is inserted in to a queue, and it's being handled later, most probably after the interrupt handler is finished.

So why doesn't it work ?

Comment: Consider the possibility that your print-call just fills up the buffer, forcing it to flush. What will happen when doing I/O in your interrupt handler?

Comment: YES, it's really that bad. Thank you, and good night.

Comment: It *does* work. `printk` is designed to be called from interrupt or process context. If it wasn't, it wouldn't be much use for debugging. You obviously don't call it in interrupt context in a production driver, though.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The `printk` function is not just inserting into a queue/buffer -- assuming the log level is high enough, the output from `printk` will be emitted to the console immediately, as part of the call to `printk`.  This is especially slow if the console is, say, on a serial port.  But in any case, `printk` does introduce pretty substantial overhead and can affect timing.

If you have a timing critical place where you want to get some debug output, you can look at using the `trace_printk` function in modern kernels.  This actually does just put input into the trace ringbuffer, and you can read it later.  Take a look at [this article](http://lwn.net/Articles/365835/) for full details.

Comment: How is debugfs as an alternative to the trace_printk? Is it good enough or does it have any caveats too?

Comment: That's not fully true for the kernels v3.x+ (or even starting with earlier ones) I think. OTOH the advice for `trace_printk()` I fully support.

Answer (score -10):

Yes, it is very bad since `printf` most probably is not reentrant.  What can happen is that the main program calls printf, an interrupt arrives while `printf` is executing, and then the IRQ handler calls `printf` again: very bad things may happen (e.g., deadlock, corrupt internal buffers, etc.)

Comment: The question is about `printk`, not `printf` which doesn't even exist in the kernel.  And the Linux kernel's `printk` is reentrant and can be called from interrupt context etc.  So this answer is totally misguided.

Comment: Uh, I misread the title, and the function name has a funky trailing character in his post :/

Comment: Seriously what are you trying to add in to the discussion? I wonder why that reply is not marked negative!